# How do I log in so I can open my Tapkey Lock?

Tags: java, android, tapkey

I don't know, how to authorize my app to open the tapkey lock.

I have this code, but I dont know what to insert into STRING:
`userManager.logInAsync(STRING, CancellationTokens.None)`
Do you have any idea how I can get the User Id or a Token for logging in?

If you need anything of the code just tell me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To login into the `Tapkey Mobile SDK` you need to setup and configure an `Identity Provider` which signs an `JWK Token` which has then to be exchanged against an `Tapkey Access Token`.

Find more detailed here:
https://developers.tapkey.io/mobile/authentication/

Detailed informations about using an `Identity Provider` can be found here:
https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/identity_providers/

How to create and register a `Identity Provider` and a `Token Exchange Client` can be found here:
https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/registration/#identity-provider-registration

**1. Sign a JWT Token via trusted services**

Sign via a trusted services a JWT Token for your logged in user:
https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/identity_providers/

**2. Exchange JWT Token with Tapkey Access Token**

Exchange the signed JWT Token with an Tapkey Access Token on your devices:
https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/token_exchange/

There is no specific implementation for it in the Tapkey Mobile SDK, this has to be done manually.

**3. Use the Tapkey Access Token to login**

Use the Tapkey Access Token to login into the Tapkey Mobile SDK

`userManager.logInAsync([TAPKEY_ACCESS_TOKEN], CancellationTokens.None);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried that, but I just dont get it. I have a Method getToken() with the following Content: https://tiny.rip/6Q1GqiAB1h . And I use it in `userManager.logInAsync(getToken(), CancellationTokens.None);` but I get this error: https://tiny.rip/eeyaN8F8g7 .

Comment: Please don't sign production JWT Token directly on the device, as the JWT private key must not be shared with untrusted devices.

The signed JWT Token must be exchanged against a Tapkey Access Token. This is missing in your example

Comment: How can I Exchange the token. Is there any method directly in the SDK or do I need to Code this in any other way?

Comment: There is no implementation in the Mobile SDK for that. See updated answer.

Comment: I now have this code and get this error: https://tiny.rip/vGpXJyfm2c (You can find both in the snippet.) I use the code with my other method: `tokenExchangeManager.exchangeToken(TokenUtil.getToken())`. Any idea why this doesn't work?

Comment: This error seems not to be from Tapkey. I guess it is thrown by the used OAuth Library. Which library do you use?

Comment: I use AppAuth for Android. I guess that's the Name, but it's also linked in the TapKey API Docs
Edit: Yes, the Name is AppAuth for Android

Comment: Is the ClientId you are using a "Token Exchange Client"?

Comment: Now I'm using this code: https://tiny.rip/B97ywVDrtn . I figured the problem of the error out by myself. Now I can log in. But do I need in my getToken Method (https://tiny.rip/6Q1GqiAB1h) the IpId or do I need anything else in there?